# API Platform and external JWT Provider

Tags: api-platform.com

I deployed a basic API Platform and i would like to secure all my API endpoints with an external JWT Token issued by Auth0 platform.
I managed to do it in Swagger and add the Bearer after clicking on 'Authorize' but my endpoints are still public.
I don't want to use LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle which is dedicated to trust emitted token from my understanding).

Does anybody have an idea for me to secure those endpoints with an external JWT?

Thanks

Comment: This should solve your question: https://curity.io/resources/learn/symfony-api/